# Android owner locked: Can't update phone

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, locked-out

i am samsung galaxy tab E user. I don't have custom recovery system in my device. The owner of tablet is locked and I forgot the password. I know the google account signed in owners it's mine but there is no option of using that to unlock owner. Earlier I used by creating another user but I cant update my device OS now. How do I reset owner account or get option of opening it using google account signed in in there?

Answer (score 0):

You can try  resetting the device to factory then when you'll be promoted to verify your Google account, simply put the owner account that was synced with the device then after that you can put any account and you should be able to download OTA updates